# How to express concat SQL without using raw SQL?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

The SQL just like this:

```
select a,b,concat(a,b) from table
```

But we don't want to use raw sql(whereRaw() and so on), we want to use ORM and the Query Constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this: 
**1. Attribute mode**: In your model
Add

```
protected $appends = ['con_cat'];

public function getConCatAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['A'].$this->attributes['B']
}
```

Now you can use

```
$yourModel->con_cat
```

**2. Function mode**: In your model

```
public function concatAB()
{
    return $this->attributes['A'].$this->attributes['B']
}
```

Now you can use

```
$yourModel->concatAB()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Raw Expression](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects) for concat in ORM and the Query Constructor. Like below :

```
Model::select('a','b',\DB::raw("concat(a,' ',b)"))
       ->get();
```

Comment: yeah,but is there any way we can express that without raw expression? May be use other query constructors? Sorry My boss is an obsessive and  throw this mad question and I can't handle it...